# When is the referenced entity retrieved?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

At the moment I retrieved an entity which has a ReferenceProperty, has the entity already retrieved the parent entity?
Does two reads occur in this case?
In the case that I always want the parent key and I sometimes want the parent entity data, should I not use a ReferenceProperty for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has the entity already retrieved the parent entity?

No.

> Does two reads occur in this case?

No

> In the case that I always want the parent key and I sometimes want the
>   parent entity data, should I not use a ReferenceProperty for that?

A ReferenceProperty makes perfect sense in this scenario.